# Java Open BufferedWriter only once but rewrite content many times

Tags: java, performance, file-io

I am running a long running operation, Say 100k jobs. i want to update the progress of it in a file once every 100 such jobs are completed.

i am opening the file using bufferedWriter with append mode as false. Writing it and then closing it. this is done once every 100 jobs are completed. So the file open and close would have happened 1000 times. Can i optimise it further by opening and closing the file only once?

```
    public static void writeMetaData(String writeDir, JSONObject jsonObject) throws Exception {
        String filePath = writeDir.concat("/").concat("metadata.txt");
        BufferedWriter metaDataWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        metaDataWriter.write(jsonObject.toString());
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(metaDataWriter);
    }

for(int i =0 ; i < 100000; i++) {
    // do Something; 
    if(i % 100 == 0) {
        writeMetaData(writeDir, jsonObject); 
    }
}
```

File should only have a single line.

Expected file content after 100 jobs:
`progress: 100` 
Expected file content after 200 jobs:
`progress: 200`

Can this be optimised further?

Comment: Then you need to initialize the writer outside `writeMetaData`. And I don't see why you wouldn't inline that method in your loop... unless you're calling it from many places.

Comment: Why can't you pass a collection of objects to this method instead passing them one by one?

Comment: @ernest_k: doing so would only append to the file instead of rewrite. eg: doing so will have 1000 lines in the file instead of single line.

Comment: Rather than writing the progress into a file, you can also make/delete a file/folder and name it according to the progress.

Comment: "Can I optimise it further by opening and closing the file only once?": no.

Comment: Why do you need to write that file anyway? Do you have another process reading it?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, an expression like `writeDir.concat("/").concat("metadata.txt")` is reducing readability *and* performance. A straight-forward `writeDir + "/" + "metadata.txt"` will provide better performance. But since you’re constructing a string merely for constructing a `Path`, it’s even more straight-forward not to do the `Path`’s job in your code but rather use `Paths.get(writeDir, "metadata.txt")`.

You can not rewind a `BufferedWriter` but you can rewind a `FileChannel`. Therefore, to keep the channel open and rewind it when needed, you have to construct a new writer after rewinding:

```java
public static void writeMetaData(FileChannel ch, JSONObject jsonObj) throws IOException {
    ch.position(0);
    if(ch.size() > 0) ch.truncate(0);

    Writer w = Channels.newWriter(ch, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder(), 8192);
    w.write(jsonObj.toString());
    w.flush();
}
```

```java
try(FileChannel ch = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(writeDir, "metadata.txt"),
        StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        // do Something;
        if(i % 100 == 0) {
            writeMetaData(ch, jsonObject);
        }
    }
}
```

It’s important that the use of the `Writer` ends with `flush()` to force the write of all buffered data, but not `close()` as that would also close the underlying channel. Note that this code does not wrap the writer into a `BufferedWriter`; encoding text as UTF-8 is already a buffered operation and by requesting a larger buffer for the encoder, matching `BufferedWriter`’s default buffer size, we get the same effect of buffering without the copying overhead.

Since writing is not an end in itself, there’s a question left regarding your reading side. If the reader is trying to read the data in some intervals, there’s the risk of overlapping with the write, getting incomplete data.

You could use

```java
public static void writeMetaData(FileChannel ch, JSONObject jsonObj) throws IOException {
    try(FileLock lock = ch.lock()) {
        ch.position(0);
        if(ch.size() > 0) ch.truncate(0);

        Writer w = Channels.newWriter(ch, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder(), 8192);
        w.write(jsonObj.toString());
        w.flush();
    }
}
```

to lock the file during the write. But depending on the system, file locking might not be mandatory but only affect readers also trying to get a read lock.

---

When you use JDK 11 or newer, you may consider using

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    // do Something;
    if(i % 100 == 0) {
        Files.writeString(Paths.get(writeDir, "metadata.txt"), jsonObject.toString());
    }
}
```

which clearly wins on simplicity (yes, that’s the complete code, no additional method required). The default options do already include the desired `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` and `StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING`.

While it does open and close the file internally, it has some other performance tweaks which may compensate. Especially in the likely case that the string consists of ASCII characters only, as the implementation will simply write the string’s internal array directly to the file then.

Answer (score 4):

A Stream does not allow to go back and rewrite content. A way to achieve what you want is using a [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).
Its [`setLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#setLength-long-) method will truncate the file if you pass `0`.

Here is a simple example:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void updateFile(RandomAccessFile raf, String content) throws IOException
    {
        raf.setLength(0);
        raf.write(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try(RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("metadata.txt", "rw"))
        {
            updateFile(raf, "progress: 100");
            updateFile(raf, "progress: 200");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File operations are typically buffered by the underlying kernel, and so you're unlikely to see much of a performance benefit by keeping an open file descriptor for this kind of low throughput application.

Keeping your code as a single operation that gets to leave no state after it finishes, rather than designing it as a continuous rewindable stream, makes for an elegant, simple, and unless you've specifically requested synchronous IO, then also sufficiently performant implementation that gets to benefit from the optimizations of all of the layers that sit beneath it.

When you do get measurable impedance to performance by this, which I suspect you never will, you could use the `RandomAccessFile` API, or go unnecessarily lower level by using `FileChannel` as others already specified.

I think you shouldn't compromise the simplicity/elegance of your design for this kind of micro-optimization, which in the grand scheme of things, is guaranteed to be insignificant (one tiny write operation per 100 jobs processed).